# Precise solutions for Boolean Delay Equations

Tags: python, math, boolean, delay

I am trying to write an algorithm to compute solutions for a Boolean delay equation in continuous time. Something like *x(t) = x(t-tau1) ^ x(t-tau2)*, where *x(t)* is a Boolean-valued function of time, *^* represents the XOR operator, *tau1* and *tau2* are constant delays in continuous time (float).

I managed to write code to compute the solution in discretized time, sampled at equal time intervals, say *dt*.

Here is a Python script calculating and plotting one of those solutions:

```py
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 100000
t = linspace(0.0, 40.0, n)
dt = t[1] - t[0]

# atrasos nas duas linhas (números "reais" float)
tau1 = 1.0
tau2 = 1.3 #2/3 #6/7
# versão em int dos atrasos
itau1 = int(tau1/dt)
itau2 = int(tau2/dt)
# o maior dos atrasos
itaumax = max(itau1, itau2)
# o menor dos atrasos
itaumin = min(itau1, itau2)


# arrays para armazenar as variáveis dinâmicas
# saída do XOR
XO = zeros(n, dtype = int)
# saída da linha 1
XA = zeros(n, dtype = int)
# saída da linha 2
XB = zeros(n, dtype = int)

# estado inicial
XA[0] = 0
XB[0] = 0
XO[0:itaumin] = 1

# inicia cálculo no tempo
for i in range(itaumin,itaumax):
  #  t[i] = i*dt , dt = (tf-t0)/n = 0.01 para tf = 20, n = 1000
  if i-itau1 >= 0:
    XA[i] = XO[i-itau1] # a saída da linha 1 é XO atrasado de tau1
  if i-itau2 >= 0:
    XB[i] = XO[i-itau2] # a saída da linha 2 é XO atrasado de tau2
  XO[i] = XA[i] ^ XB[i] #  ^ corresponde a XOR de inteiros

for i in range(itaumax,n):
  #  t[i] = i*dt , dt = (tf-t0)/n = 0.01 para tf = 20, n = 1000
  XA[i] = XO[i-itau1] # a saída da linha 1 é XO atrasado de tau1
  XB[i] = XO[i-itau2] # a saída da linha 2 é XO atrasado de tau2
  XO[i] = XA[i] ^ XB[i] #  ^ corresponde a XOR de inteiros

plt.figure('Série temporal', figsize=(15,8))
ax1 = plt.subplot(3,1,1)

plt.plot(t-itaumax*dt, XA,color = "blue", label = "A")
plt.xlabel(r'Tempo')
plt.ylabel(r'A')


ax2 = plt.subplot(3,1,2, sharex = ax1)

plt.plot(t-itaumax*dt, XB,color = "red", label = "B")
plt.xlabel(r'Tempo')
plt.ylabel(r'B')

ax3 = plt.subplot(3,1,3, sharex = ax1)

plt.xlabel(r'Tempo')
#plt.plot(t-itaumax*dt, XA,color = "blue", label = "A")
#plt.plot(t, XB,color = "red", label = "B")
plt.plot(t, XO,color = "black", label = "A^B")
plt.ylabel(r'A ^ B')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

But I am finding it difficult to write and algorithm to express the exact times where transitions (i.e. changes from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0) take place. The difficulty arises from transition times colliding and annihilating each other. In the equation, any transition that happened at time *t* will possibly generate two transitions at times *t+tau1* and *t+tau2*, except if there are two possible times *t* causing the same future transitions, in which case the new transitions "collide" and annihilate each other.

If it  was just repeated transitions, I could just generate all possible transitions and discard the ones that are repeated, but once a pair of transitions collide they should not generate new transitions, and hence I also need to discard all the other transitions that originated from the discarded pair.

Here is an example of the "exact" solution: Suppose that we start with a single transition `t[0]` at time *t = 0.0*, this one is going to produce two new transitions at times `t[1] = tau1` and `t[2] = tau2`. The new ones would produce `t[3] = tau1+tau1 == 2*tau1`, `t[4] = tau1+tau2`, and `t[5] = tau2+tau1`, `t[6] = tau2+tau2`, except that `t[4]` and `t[5]` are identical and should both be removed. We then should proceed to replace the value of `t[4]` with the one stored in `t[6]`, and calculate the new set of transitions from `t[3]` and the new `t[4]`.

With numbers: For `tau1 = 2.0/3.0` and `tau2 = 1.0`, the expected solution is

```
t[1] = 0.66667
t[2] = 1.0
t[3] = 1.33333 
t[4] = 2.33333  ## Note that 1.6667 was removed because t[1]+tau2 == t[2]+tau1
t[5] = 3.0      ## 2.0 was also removed because t[3]+tau1 == t[2]+tau2
t[6] = 3.33333
t[7] = 3.66667  ## etc.
```

Comment: Could you please give an example? It's hard to understand what you're talking about. perhaps show us an example with 10 or 20 successive values for t in your discretized time, and the corresponding x(t), and explain what your algorithm should output and why.

Comment: I also have no idea what "collide" and "annihilate" could possibly mean

Comment: Also have no idea what you mean when you say that some transitions "generate new transitions".

Comment: I improved the explanation of the problem, added an example, and code for the discrete-time case. I hope I have make the problem understandable this time. I also realized that my discrete-time solution sometimes (for some values of delays) gives short pulses that should not have appeared if it was exact. It's probably due to the discretization or rounding errors. That's why I would like to have an "exact" solution. Thanks for your interest @Stef.

Comment: Focusing on the very last paragraph of your question , and the example given with t[1] through t[7], I think a simple solution would be to use a priority queue to store the generated times, so that you only generate new times from the earliest time in the queue; when dequeuing, if there are duplicates at the top of the queue, trash them.

Answer (score 1):

Focusing on the very last paragraph of your question , and the example given with t[1] through t[7], I think a simple solution would be to use a priority queue to store the generated times, so that you only generate new times from the earliest time in the queue; when dequeuing, if there are duplicates at the front of the queue, trash them.

```py
import heapq

def fequal(x, y):            # never compare floats with == directly
    return abs(x-y) < 0.0001

def gen_times(t0, tau):
    queue = [t0]
    while queue:
        head = heapq.heappop(queue)
        if not queue or not fequal(queue[0], head):  # element is unique
            yield head
            for t in tau:
                heapq.heappush(queue, head+t)
        else:                              # element is duplicate
            while queue and fequal(queue[0], head):
                heapq.heappop(queue)


# TESTING
from itertools import islice
print(list(islice(gen_times(0.0, [0.2, 1.0]), 12)))
# [0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6000000000000001, 0.8, 1.2, 1.6, 2.2, 2.4000000000000004, 3.2, 4.2, 4.4]
```

Note that 1.2 was **not** removed, because 1.0 was removed, so 1.2 was never generated as 1.0+0.2, only as 0.2+1.0.

Comment: Sorry, @Stef, your solution doesn't work past the 14th iteration with tau1 = 2/3 and tau2 = 1.0. It starts to produce repeated transitions that should also have collided. Notice that collisions may happen with any of the previous transitions, not just the last one. But I think the use of a heap queue is definitely in the right direction.

Comment: Here is part of the output of `print(list(islice(gen_times(0.0, [tau1, tau2]), 20)))`: `... 6.0, 6.666666666666666, 6.666666666666667, 7.0, 7.333333333333333, 7.333333333333334, 7.666666666666666, 8.333333333333334, 8.666666666666666]`. Maybe it's caused by rounding error? (The last digits seem different on the repeated values).

Comment: @HugoCavalcante Ooooops, of course, I had integers in my head while I wrote the code. Floats should almost never be compared using `==` or `!=`. In the code above you should replace `queue[0] != head` with `abs(queue[0] - head) > 0.0001` and `queue[0] == head` with `abs(queue[0] - head) < 0.0001`

Comment: Yes! It works beautifully and very fast. I changed the floats do Decimals from the `decimal` module, to increase precision. Thank you so much!